# What/Where is Tasks.Future.Create and what is its equivalent?

Tags: .net, multithreading, f#, task

I was looking up [this article on F# optimizations](http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.nl/2009/07/ocaml-vs-f-burrows-wheeler.html) and was curious about the line mentioning `Tasks.Future.Create`. It seems to create a task in the future and it seems to follow the [Futures and Promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) pattern. The same method is mentioned in some other places as well, like in [this thread on benchmarking F#, Java, C#](http://www.microsoftfaqs.com/msg/144633051.aspx), where it was also used in the F# code.

I was wondering, would the aforementioned F# code, copied here for reference in case the link dies, work quite the same with something like `Tasks.Task<T>`, or should I be using a different threading primitive?

```
open System.Threading

let inline sort cmp (a: _ array) =
  let inline swap i j =
    let t = a.[i]
    a.[i] <- a.[j]
    a.[j] <- t
  let rec qsort l u =
    if l < u then
      swap l ((l + u) / 2)
      let mutable m = l
      for i=l+1 to u do
        if cmp a.[i] a.[l] < 0 then
          m <- m + 1
          swap m i
      swap l m
      if u-l > 1000 then
        let m = m
        let f = Tasks.Future.Create(fun () -> qsort l (m-1))
        qsort (m+1) u
        f.Value
      else
        qsort l (m-1)
        qsort (m+1) u
  qsort 0 (a.Length-1)

let inline cmp (str: _ array) i j =
  let rec cmp i j =
    if i=str.Length then 1 else
      if j=str.Length then -1 else
        let c = compare str.[i] str.[j] in
        if c<>0 then c else
          cmp (i+1) (j+1)
  cmp i j

let bwt (str: byte array) =
  let n = str.Length
  let a = Array.init n (fun i -> i)
  sort (fun i j -> cmp str i j) a
  Array.init n (fun i -> str.[(a.[i] + n - 1) % n])
```

Note: it is my guess that this was a method in a preview edition of the TPL.

Comment: I think your guess is spot-on. It looks like you want `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Task.Result` (instead of `Value`).

Comment: @Daniel: seems likely, thanks for looking up the correct calls. I'll experiment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. It dated back to a paper about [Design of Task Parallel Library](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=77368). Quoting a relevant part of the paper:

> Futures are a variation of tasks, where the associated action computes
>   a result:
>
> ```cs
> delegate T Func<T>();
> class Future<T> : Task{
>   Future (Func<T> function);
>   T Value{ get; } // does an implicit wait
> }
> ```
>
> A future is constructed with a delegate having the Func type where
>   T is the return type of the delegate. The result of the future is
>   retrieved through the Value property, which calls Wait internally to
>   ensure that the task has completed and the result value has been
>   computed. Since Wait is called, calling Value will throw any exception
>   that was raised during the computation of the future value. One can
>   view futures as returning either a result value or an exceptional
>   value.

In TPL now you can do everything using [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class. As @Daniel said, your example can be written:

```ml
let f = Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> qsort l (m-1))
qsort (m+1) u
f.Result
```

I think the future pattern is even more useful when you have a task graph with complex dependencies. You may want to learn more about the pattern in the excellent book [Parallel Programming with Microsoft .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963556.aspx) (which contains many good [F# samples](http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/69940#812665)).

Comment: It is exactly a (deep) call graph with complex dependencies that brought me to considering this. Thanks for finding the talk!